# Dynamic Access of Multi dimensional Python Array

Tags: python, numpy

I am a python newbie. I was confused on how to access array element dynamically.

I have a list b= [1,2,5,8] that I dynamically obtain so its length can vary. With help of this list I need to update multi-dimensional array as mArr[1] [2] [5] [8] . The length of the list and array dimension matches as given in the example

Basically, I am looking a technique to access a multi dimensional array with respect to the list "b" as in the form of : marr[b]. This m-array is also dynamically created.

I tried looking on to tutorials of numpy but was not figure out the solution.Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the dimensions are `[1,2,5,8]` you can use numbers `0, 0..1, 0..4, 0..7` for each dimension.

Numpy lets you access positions with tuples:

```
shape = [1, 2, 5, 8]
pos = [0, 1, 1, 3]

my_array = np.ones(shape)
my_array[tuple(pos)] # will return 1
```

Comment: no need to do that reshape thing. Just pass the shape as parameter to np.ones

Comment: tx for the quick reply..can you elaborate it more..i am confused in third line...what if, if I have b=[3,4,7,8,10,20] next time, how to access my array as myarr[3][4][7][8][10][20]....

Comment: @iinception, the third line creates an array, only the fourth line is concerned with accessing.

Comment: tx all...tuple was the keyword I was looking forr.. :)

Comment: @iinception, now I understood. [1,2,5,8] is not the dimension, so you just use `b = (1,2,5,8)` and `myarr[b]` or `myarr[tuple(b)]` if b is a list

Comment: @iinception, tuple isn't technically a keyword. Its a function.

Comment: @WinstonEwert tuple isn't technically a function. It's a class

Comment: @JBernardo, hmm... are the builtin types actually classes or just types? But yeah, not a function at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function like:

```
def array_update(b, marr, value):
  if len(b) > 1:
    return array_update(b[1:], marr[b[0]], value)
  marr[b[0]] = value
```

Given b=[1,2,5,8], to set the value of mArr[1][2][5][8] to `foo`, you would call:

```
array_update(b, mArr, 'foo')
```