# Accessing elements of multi-dimensional list, given a list of indexes

Tags: python, list

I have a multidimensional list `F`, holding elements of some type. So, if for example the rank is 4, then the elements of `F` can be accessed by something like `F[a][b][c][d]`.

Given a list `L=[a,b,c,d]`, I would like to access `F[a][b][c][d]`. My problem is that my rank is going to be changing, so I cannot just have `F[L[0]][L[1]][L[2]][L[3]]`.

Ideally, I would like to be able to do `F[L]` and get the element `F[a][b][c][d]`. I think something like this can be done with `numpy`, but for the types of arrays that I'm using, `numpy` is not suitable, so I want to do it with python lists.

How can I have something like the above?

**Edit:** For a specific example of what I'm trying to achieve, see the demo in Martijn's answer.

Comment: I am aware that my question looks a bit sloppy. I haven't managed to find a better way of expressing it.

Comment: I also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789143/dynamic-access-of-multi-dimensional-python-array However, it is not a duplicate, since it only talks about numpy arrays..

Comment: You can make it better, by giving a sample input and expected output

Comment: "but for the types of arrays that I'm using, numpy is not suitable" are you sure? What about Pandas dataframes?

Comment: Would something like F[(a,b,c,d)] as structure would satisfy you ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to access consecutive elements:

```
from functools import reduce  # forward compatibility
import operator

reduce(operator.getitem, indices, somelist)
```

In Python 3 `reduce` was moved to the `functools` module, but in Python 2.6 and up you can always access it in that location.

The above uses the [`operator.getitem()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem) to apply each index to the previous result (starting at `somelist`).

Demo:

```
>>> import operator
>>> somelist = ['index0', ['index10', 'index11', ['index120', 'index121', ['index1220']]]]
>>> indices = [1, 2, 2, 0]
>>> reduce(operator.getitem, indices, somelist)
'index1220'
```

Comment: Bless. Working on refactoring someone else's code and this saves me a lot of headaches from manual indexing based on cases of dimension. Will probably remove it altogether, eventually, but now I don't have to look at it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
def get_element(lst, indices):
    if indices:
        return get_element(lst[indices[0]], indices[1:])
    return lst
```

Test:

```
get_element([[["element1"]], [["element2"]], "element3"], [2])
'element3'
get_element([[["element1"]], [["element2"]], "element3"], [0, 0])
['element1']
```

Or if you want an iterative version:

```
def get_element(lst, indices):
    res = lst
    for index in indices:
        res = res[index]
    return res
```

Test:

```
get_element([[["element1"]], [["element2"]], "element3"], [1, 0])
['element2']
```